# How can I implement Android Maps extensions on Android Studio?

Tags: android, maps

I need to implement Android Maps extensions in my project, but I can't find how to do it. I don't know how to import those extensions to my project.
I've tried to change dependencies.
I need a fragment like this:

```
  android:name="pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got the answer to this but just in case, you can go to File > Project structure of Android Studio.

It will prompt you with the "Project Structure" window, go to Dependencies tab and make sure your app is selected on the modules section on the left.

Click the plus (+) sign, choose Library Dependency and search for the extension if available. Click OK and wait for Gradle to finish importing the library before you can use it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean this library...

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
}
```

but you may have already solved your problem.